# Why RadFilter is not detecting Columns correctly?

Tags: filter, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

I am having trouble that RadFilter is not detecting the columns correctly. I bind my RadGrid through code in Asp like:

RadGrid1.DataSource = myDataSource;
RadGrid.DataBind();

RadFilter is only binding those columns which are bind through  and ignoring those who are in . Is this a known issue? as I didn't see any thread talking about this problem. Waiting for help immediately.

Regards,
Wasim.

Comment: The third paragraph doesn't make much sense, could you clarify by chance?

Comment: I mean to say that if I am using <Telerik:GridTemplateColumn> then the RadFilter is not recognizing that column name in its list. Well I figured it out. Its a bug of RadFilter that is only consider those columns who has a static property of DataField. It doesn't supports dynamic data binding.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly, you need to add FilterFieldEditors to the RadFilter for any field that is not represented in the DataSource for the grid.

You can add filters dynamically with the following code.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var fieldName = "myDynamicFilterField";
        var friendlyName = "Friendly Dynamic Field";
        var newTextFieldEditor = new RadFilterTextFieldEditor();

        filter.FieldEditors.Add(newTextFieldEditor);
        newTextFieldEditor.FieldName = fieldName;       // name filter will used for filter exressions
        newTextFieldEditor.DisplayName = friendlyName;  // name use will see when they selected a field to filter

        // ** Repeat for all dynamic fields **
    }
}
```

I was able to get a working version using auto generated columns and custom added columns, but ran into many other problems.  I ended up just dynamically creating all the filter fields (as shown above) from the data source and applying the filter expression to the grid.